# 2-Way protocol oriented data passing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass data back and forth between two `viewControllers` to maintain the data when segueing. I have a `mainMenuVC` and a `SettingsVC`. The settings are chosen inside the `SettingsVC` and then passed to the `mainMenuVC` to be stored, however, it seems that this does not happen and I am not sure why.

This is the code in `mainMenuVC` which conforms to the `transferSettings` protocol.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "optionsSegue" {
        let receivingVC:SettingsVC = segue.destination as! SettingsVC

        receivingVC.settingsDelegate = self
        self.settingsDelegate = receivingVC

        if self.settingsDelegate != nil{
            if self.currentSettings == nil {
                print("currentNil")
                self.currentSettings = GameOptions()
            }
            self.currentSettings.description()
            self.settingsDelegate.storeGameSettings(settings: self.currentSettings)
        }else{ print("settingsDelegate in MainMenuVC nil")}
    }
```

And this is the code inside `SettingsVC' which also conforms to the protocol above.

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "settingsReturn" {
        let recievingVC:MainMenuVC = segue.destination as! MainMenuVC
        ///Set the delegate of MainMenu to SettingsVC
        recievingVC.settingsDelegate = self

        if self.settingsDelegate != nil {
            if self.ScrollView.settingsSelected != nil{
                self.ScrollView.saveUserSettings()
                print("settingsVC")
                self.ScrollView.settingsSelected.description()
                self.settingsDelegate.storeGameSettings(settings: self.ScrollView.settingsSelected)
            }else{ print("No stored settings in the SettingsVC")}
        }else{print("SettingsDelegate in SettingsVC is nil")}
    }
}
```

The way I assumed this would work is that my data would simply pushed back and forth between the two `viewControllers`, but after examining with breakpoints, I found that after `prepareforsegue` is finished executing, the properties that store the data in the `recievingVC` are nil, thereby reseting the process.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an unwind segue to return to the mainMenuVC?  Is `self.currentSettings` a  class instance?

Comment: I'm not using an unwind segue. I simply used interface builder to cntrl drag a segue both forward and back. self.currentSettings is a property of the `mainMenuVC` that is supposed to store the data passed from the `mainMenuVC' and back into it.

Comment: You need to use an unwind segue, otherwise you will be creating an ever-deeper stack of view controllers.  You don't need to use a protocol or delegation pattern if your settings are a class instance (rather than a struct); You can simply assign the settings instance as you do in `prepareForSegue` and the settings view controller will be modifying that instance, so there is no need to pass anything back.

Comment: Check this Answer..

http://stackoverflow.com/a/41014074/5172413

Comment: So as I understand, the reason my code doesn't work is that prepare for segue basically causes an infinite stack of `ViewControllers` so I am never really "returning" but rather going into a new `ViewController`? And unwind from segue assures that you actually return to the `ViewController` called you originally?

Comment: Yes, that is right;  Apple has a tech note on Unwind Segues; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I'd shoot you an up vote if I could :)