# How to pass data on back button through navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass the data on the back button of the navigation bar in my project, help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41014074/5172413

Answer (score 0):

I have two View Controllers.I am passing the data from Second View Controller to First View Controller using Custom Delegate.

Here I used the Custom Delegate and NSNotification Center method.

Custom Delegate

> First we can use  Custom Protocol Delegate
>
> `@class SecondViewController;`
>
> `@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>`
>
> `- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)secondViewController didEnterText:(NSString *)text;`
>
> `@end`
>
> Then we need to Assign the delegate here.
>
> `@property (nonatomic, assign)id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;`
>
> Very importantly we have to set the Custom Delegate Method in the
>   Second View Controller.Because where we send the data to first view
>   controller once we click the done button in second view controller.
>
> `[self.delegate secondViewController:self didEnterText:self.nameTextField.text];`
>
> Finally we must call the Custom Delegate Method in First View
>   Controller, where we get the data and assign that data to label.Now
>   you can see the passed data using custom delegate.
>
> `#import "SecondViewController.h"`
>
> `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>`

When you need to call Custom Delegate in First View Controller.m

> `- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController
>   *)secondViewController didEnterText:(NSString *)text    {
>        self.labelName.text = text; //Getting the data and assign the data to label here.    }`

But First when you navigate to Second View Controller, you need to do below things

> -(IBAction)gotoNextView:(id)sender;
>
> {
>
> //Set the delegate here
>
> `secondViewController.delegate = self;`
>
> .....//navigating code
>
> }

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class SecondViewController;
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)secondViewController didEnterText:(NSString *)text;
@end
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign)id<SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;  
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;//It must connect as outlet connection
- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController ()
@end
@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//Either use NSNotification or Delegate
- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender;
{
          //Use Notification
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"passingDataFromSecondViewToFirstView" object:self.nameTextField.text];
          //OR Custom Delegate
     [self.delegate secondViewController:self didEnterText:self.nameTextField.text];
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
      [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Then

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelName; //You must connect the label with outlet connection
- (IBAction)gotoNextView:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   //addObserver here...
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFromPreviousViewControllerNotificationReceived:) name:@"passingDataFromSecondViewToFirstView" object:nil];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

//addObserver Method here....
- (void)textFromPreviousViewControllerNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   // set text to label...
   NSString *string = [notification object];
   self.labelName.text = string;
}
- (IBAction)gotoNextView:(id)sender;
{
   //If you use storyboard
   SecondViewController *secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
   //OR  If you use XIB
   SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
   secondViewController.delegate = self;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}

//Calling custom delegate method
- (void)secondViewController:(SecondViewController *)secondViewController didEnterText:(NSString *)text
{
   self.labelName.text = text; //Getting the data and assign the data to label here.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when a back button is pressed, in viewDidDisapear:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController) {
        //moving back
        //pass to viewCollection delegate and update UI
        [self.delegate passBackSavedData:self.dataModel];
     }
}
```